# How to get the text of an editable TextBlock in GoJS?

Tags: javascript, gojs

How to get the text of an editable TextBlock in GoJS?

Comment: Hi Ricardo, welcome to SO. Your question doesn't show sufficient research effort. Kindly read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking.  The literal answer to your question is that you can get the text string from any **TextBlock** by getting its [TextBlock.text](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/TextBlock.html#text) property value.

But you mention that the TextBlock is editable, so maybe you are asking about how to get the previous value of the TextBlock.text during editing.

First, the validation predicate is given both the original string as well as the new proposed string: the [TextBlock.textValidation](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/TextBlock.html#textValidation) and  [TextEditingTool.textValidation](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/TextEditingTool.html#textValidation) properties and the [TextEditingTool.isValidText](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/TextEditingTool.html#isValidText) method.

Second, the "TextEdited" **DiagramEvent** gets the original string value as the **DiagramEvent.parameter**: [DiagramEvent](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/DiagramEvent.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your diagram's nodeTemplate. This helps.

> $(go.TextBlock, {
>                           editable: true
>                       })

```
 myDiagram.nodeTemplate =

    $(go.Node, "Horizontal", {
            isTreeExpanded: false,
            click: showDetail
        },
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", {
                fill: "#cce6ff", // the default fill, if there is no data-binding
                stroke: "#6699ff",
                height: 40,
                strokeWidth: 2,
                portId: "",
                cursor: "pointer", // the Shape is the port, not the whole Node
            }, new go.Binding("fill", "fill")),
            $(go.TextBlock, {
                    editable: true
                },
                new go.Binding("text", "text"))
        ),
        $("TreeExpanderButton", { alignment: go.Spot.Bottom, alignmentFocus: go.Spot.Top }, { visible: true })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger edit textblock use below cade

```
var textBlock = myDiagram.findNodeForKey(nodekey).findObject('TextBlockName');
if (myDiagram.commandHandler.canEditTextBlock(textBlock))
    myDiagram.commandHandler.editTextBlock(textBlock);
```